# string split in r at specific position

Tags: r

need a quick help in spliting a string in two columns.
the below example data :

```
vrn
AA53C0624
AA53C0625
AA53C0626
AA53C0628
AA53C0629
```

expected output (split should occur at 5th place for every records)

```
vrn       character numeric
AA53C0624   AA53C   0624
AA53C0625   AA53C   0625
AA53C0626   AA53C   0626
AA53C0628   AA53C   0628
AA53C0629   AA53C   0629
```

Thanks

Comment: If it is fixed that you want to split at 5th position. why not try `substr(vrn, 1, 5)` and `substr(vrn, 6, nchar(vrn))` ?

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but is it possible to get the output in one statement/code?

Comment: `data.frame(vrn, character = substr(vrn, 1, 5), numeric = substr(vrn, 6, nchar(vrn)))`